# SystemProperties from maven failsafe plugin with Spock Tests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spock, maven-surefire-plugin

I am trying to get maven failsafe to execute my integration tests, however I am having a problem with the server port being correctly assigned to the system properties.

My failsafe plugin configuration:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.21.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>integration-tests</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <test.server.port>${tomcat.http.port}</test.server.port>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
                <skipTests>${skip.integration.tests}</skipTests>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

My spock test configuration:

```java
def "verifies port is being set correctly"() {
    expect:
    System.getProperties().getProperty('test.server.port') != null
}
```

When I run the test, `test.server.port` does not appear in my system properties array. However, if I change it to `asdf` or anything NOT test.server.port, it then appears in my system properties.

Comment: I have no problem with that, not even using the exact same variable names. Thus, your problem probably is in another part of one of your POMs. Maybe somewhere that system variable is being unset for whatever reason. It is more likely that `tomcat.http.port` is not set when variable expansion for Failsafe takes place, even though you expect it to be. This is the part you do not show here. Please provide a complete [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for me to reproduce the problem (if necessary, push a minimal project to GitHub), then I can take a look.

Comment: I forgot to mention: `mvn help:effective-pom` if your friend. Save the output and search through it or show it to me, then we should be able to spot what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

The fix was to use Spring Boot's random port for environment initialization

```
@SpringBootTest(
        classes = OrderQueueApplication.class,
        webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT
)
```